# Is there a way to silence phone calls but not text messages on an iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to have my text messages still make a noise, but I do not want phone calls other than my contacts ringing. I don't think Do Not Disturb will do this, but is there a way that someone else has discovered?

Answer (score 1):

You can set Do Not Disturb to Everyone, No-One, Favourites... or any Contacts group

[image]

Comment: I think the OP asked for text message only notifications - and not contact specific settings.

Comment: "do not want phone calls other than my contacts ringing" - sounds like just what they asked to me. Let the OP clarify, if necessary.

Comment: True - but the Text messages will also be silenced.

Comment: Rainer is right. I know how to do what Tetsujin suggested and make only my contacts ring, but my texts are silenced no matter who calls. I would like my texts to make noise. My number got picked up by some scam company so it rings all day long, so I put on DND but then I never hear my texts.

Comment: You could either block the offending numbers [plus report them to your country's authority on spam calls] or set your default ringtone to silent, then add a non-silent tone to every number in contacts. There is no 'if I don't know it, hide it' setting, for obvious reasons.